# Find entries that match 2 criteria, one based on a column one based on order

Tags: linux, bash, filter

I have a tab-delimited file look like this. First column is read name and third is a column specifying if the read is Bacteria or Eukaryota. Each read could have many entries/hits. I want to extract reads that their **first**  hit ( first entry of them in the row) is Bacteria.

```
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN590686.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN590686.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN590686.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN590686.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN590686.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN590686.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LT700188.1 Bacteria
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN598496.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN597789.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223 LN596327.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:18258:19492 AL139347.10 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN600047.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN594833.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN590681.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN590681.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN590681.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN590681.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN590681.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN590681.1 Eukaryota
A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:31385:19554 LN590673.1 Eukaryota
```

Many thanks
A.

Comment: So on your sample, if should output nothing right? as the only *Bacteria* is `A00643:620:HFM7YDSX5:1:1101:9064:18223` but had a *hit* as a `Eukaryota` before. It would help if you provided a more useful example with all possibilities and an expected output

Comment: Sure you're right. I will update it

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly:

```
awk -F '\t' '!seen[$1]++ && $3 == "Bacteria"' < your-file
```

Would print lines for which the first field has not already seen before and the 3rd field is `Bacteria`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Let me ask one more thing , how to modify this if I want to keep entries that have hits ONLY to Bacteria?